# Python issue. Mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having some issues with the following code. I've spent half the night trying to get this to work. I'm running a xampp server locally for testing. I have some stuff commented as I was testing, and experimenting around.

Error: http://pastebin.com/SFzyBLRp

```
    if(nigcon.execute("SELECT * FROM `USER` WHERE `username` = '" + username + "' AND `password` = "' + password + '"")):
AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Code: http://pastebin.com/LE6fmek4

```
# Login Menu
# Author BlackWidow Aka Zachary
# intgamer.net or sinfulandroid.net
# Purpose Login Script for the Network Chat

import time
import sys
import MySQLdb


def loginmenu():
        print("Welcome to International Gamers Network Chat")
        print ""
        time.sleep(1)
        #connect to the sql db
        nigcon = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","testing" )
        #creation of the cursor
        cursor = nigcon.cursor()
        print "Connected to Login Server"
        print ""
        print "Please input your information"
        time.sleep(1)
        username = raw_input("Username: ")
        #if( username == 'BlackWidow' ):
        password = raw_input("Password: ")
        if(nigcon.execute("SELECT * FROM `USER` WHERE `username` = '" + username + "' AND `password` = "' + password + '"")):
        #if(cursor.execute("Select * FROM 'USER' WHERE 'username' '='" + username + "' AND password '=" + password + "'")):
           db.commit()
           print "Logged In"

loginmenu()
```

Comment: According to the documentation for MySQL-Python the execute call is only done on the cursor, which you have commented out. What happens when you run the commented part of your code with "cursor.execute"? Is it the same error?

Comment: Wow. I'm such an moron. Sorry, it's been a really long day ahaha. I'm not the brightest when it comes to mysql. 

I'm getting this error now 

http://pastebin.com/82GSn3Q7

Comment: This seems like a string formatting issue in your query. Update your original post to reflect the latest issue. I'll post what I think your string should look like.

Comment: Thanks alot! I figured it out. Here is the working version 

http://pastebin.com/0yThwfq3

Comment: Awesome. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Use `your_cursor.execute()` instead of `your_connection.execute()`.

Meanwhile, `nigcon = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","testing")` may throw exception.

```
#I would try to get a handle in this way.
try:
    hanler = MySQLdb.connect(
                    host=your_host,
                    port=your_port
                    user=your_user,
                    passwd=your_passwd,
                    db=your_db)
    hanler.autocommit(True)
except MySQLdb.OperationalError as ex:
    return False
```

And to `execute` your sql, You need a `cursor`.

```
#I would do all of this in this way
if hanler is None:
    return False
cur = self.hanler.cursor()
try:
    cur.execute(sql)
except MySQLdb.ProgrammingError as ex:
    return False
```

A little advice on your `execute` style. Try the `execute(query, args)` way.

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username = %s AND password=%s"
cur.execute(sql,(your_usename, your_passwd))
```